# Package quoting and \chapter

Tags: koma-script, quoting

I use the [`quoting`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package to set quoting in my master thesis. In the following MWE a found a strange bug.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{quoting}[font={small}]
\blindtext
\end{quoting}
\blindtext

\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
\begin{quoting}[font={small}]
\blindtext
\end{quoting}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The code produces the error

> \do undefined. \begin{quoting}[font={small}]

When the `font={small}` is set as a package option, the error doesn't occur.

How can i fix it?

The MWE in [writelatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com/548982whrvmn)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\do` is a “scratch” control sequence, that's used in many places in the internal macros of LaTeX.

Usually it *has* a definition, which nobody should rely on, at the beginning of a document, but this doesn't happen when the class is `scrreprt`; the problem is that `typearea.sty` says, at line 206, `\let\do\relax`.

Unfortunately, `quoting` does `\renewcommand*{\do}{...}` and, with the setting left by `typearea`, this is illegal.

The only way to get around this is to redefine a couple of keys in quoting:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{quoting}
\makeatletter
\define@key{quo}{font}{%
  \def\quotingfont{}%
  \def\do##1{\appto{\quotingfont}{\csname ##1\endcsname}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}
\define@key{quo}{font+}{%
  \def\do##1{\appto{\quotingfont}{\csname ##1\endcsname}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{quoting}[font={small}]
\blindtext
\end{quoting}
\blindtext

\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
\begin{quoting}[font={small}]
\blindtext
\end{quoting}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

so that whether `\do` is defined or not becomes unimportant. Instead of using `\def` one could use

```
\define@key{quo}{font}{%
  \def\quotingfont{}%
  \providecommand{\do}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\appto{\quotingfont}{\csname ##1\endcsname}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}
```

but, since `\do` is going to be redefined anyway, using `\def` is easier.

Please, make a bug report to Thomas Tietze (aka as Lockstep).

Comment: Many thanks -- I included your fix in the upcoming version 0.1c.